# $q$-Pochhammer at root of unity

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, infinite-product, q-analogs, pochhammer-symbol

Are there any identities, papers/studies, posts, etc that go over

$$(\ln\zeta_n^k;q)_{\infty} = \prod_{m=0}^{\infty}(1-\frac{2\pi i k q^m}{n})$$
which is sometimes called the $q$-Pochhammer or [quantum dilogarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_dilogarithm), but evaluated at $z = \ln\zeta_n^k$, i.e $n$-th root of unity to some power $k \leq n$. The motivation behind this is that this would be like a $q$-root of unity, as the quantum dilogarithm is also the $q$-exponential function, and hence
$$e_q\left(\frac{2\pi i k}{n}\right) = \left(\frac{2\pi i k}{n};q\right)_{\infty}$$